# Do I need a matched pair of Xeons for a dual CPU board if there is only one stepping level listed?

Tags: processor, server

I am considering purchasing 2 Xeon 2667v2 CPUs to use in a dual CPU board. The [spec page](https://ark.intel.com/products/75273/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2667-v2-25M-Cache-3-30-GHz-) (click on "Ordering and Compliance" on the left) only lists a single step level:

[image]

Does that mean that I don't need to worry about purchasing a "matched pair" of CPUs, and that any two of these CPUs should work in a dual CPU board?